# How can I upgrade from the beta to the stable version of elementary OS?

Tags: release-loki, updates

A stable version of elementary OS (0.4 Loki) was just released and I have installed a beta version of it on my system. Do I have to make a clean install to user the stable version or is it possible to upgrade from the beta?

Answer (score 6):

First install the package that provides `add-apt-repository` if it's not already installed:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

Next, remove elementary OS Beta PPA and replaced it with the stable PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:elementary-os/daily
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/stable
```

Refresh the repository information:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Remove the elementary OS pre-release packages:

```
sudo apt-get remove elementary-os-prerelease
```

Update/install the Linux kernel packages for the stable release:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-lts-xenial libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-xenial libegl1-mesa-lts-xenial
```

And finally upgrade the your system

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

It's a good idea to restart your system too.

Comment: This is not working for me. I get the error `E: Unable to locate package libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-xenial`. I guess you mean the package `libegl1-mesa-lts-xenial`?

Comment: Command `sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-lts-xenial libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-xenial libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-xenial` is senseless!

Comment: elementaryforums.com sent me an email today, which says: `There is no dist-upgrade available, unfortunately. You have to install Loki and restore your back-upped personal files afterwards.`

Answer (score 0):

First install the packages for working with PPAs:

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common ppa-purge
```

Add stable PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/stable
```

And run ppa-purge utility for disabling daily PPA and automatically synchronizing all packages from stable PPA:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:elementary-os/daily
```

Finally upgrade your system and reboot your computer after this steps:

```
sudo apt upgrade
```